# How to retrieve a newly generated image in JSP using expression

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, model-view-controller

I have a class the creates a QR code and saves it in an folder in the project.

I have a servlet that calls this QR code creator class, inserts the file path of the qr code to a database, and stores the ResultSet of the qr codes into the request.

After successfully creating the qr codes and inserting the file paths into the database, the JSP queries these using expression and outputs them using a while loop, to output all the rows in the ResultSet.

However, I get an error 404 on the images. After inspecting the element in Chrome, the img src points to the already created qr code correctly. What am I missing here?

I can give additional information if need be.

Tomcat 7.0.23
Eclipse Juno
Java SE 7

Comment: provide some code so that someone can help you

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I just need to refresh the folder containing the qr codes. After refreshing they are all displaying properly.